# Programmatically detect if Swing HTML markup rendered correctly

Tags: java, html, swing, fonts, jlabel

Is there a way to detect if a (synthatically correct) HTML rendered in a JLabel has rendered succesfully, and is displaying all intended Glyph(s)

I have the following HTML String:

```
<html><h3>Title</h3><ul><li><b>S</b>tuff</li><li><b>S</b>taff</li><li><b>S</b>tiff</li></ul></html>
```

That renders:

---

#### Title

- **S**tuff
- **S**taff
- **S**tiff

---

However, in an application, the same HTML inside a JLabel rendered as:
[image: an example]

As it can be seen, nothing is `bold`, my custom HTML parser can check for `HTML issues`, and it detects that String as correct, it then parses "correctly", and renders the Glyph(s), however, the `bold` Glyph(s) are being replaced by their default `plain` Glyph(s).

Is there a way to programatically detect that the Glyph was not used, and search for the Glyph, and replace it?

Also worth noticing:

- Similar question(s) have not yielded significant result(s). I can confirm that the HTML is always correct, and even using the "test HTML", the issue occurred.
- The Font contains the **bold** face
- Other HTML markup is being rendered correctly elsewhere(p, i, h, etc.)
- The HTML is from other supplier(s), and should not be altered/handled/defined

Comment: Are you sure the used font is supported on the platform you're running on?

Comment: @MickMnemonic Yes. I have tested with a different JLabel, with a derived font. All the Glyph(s) are there, italic, bold, italic and bold, etc. The application has the Glyph, its just not using them, and I have been unable to detect why. If you can, try to suggest any direction, that I may try to figure out why. The "problem" has been dealt with already, by scanning the Glyph(s) in the JLabel html bold range, and "drawing over", but this is a temporary hack, and should not/cannot remain. I wish to understand why this happens.

Comment: Did you try `<strong>` instead of `<b>`?

Comment: The HTML renders as expected here. As noted elsewhere, the way to go if the label / PLAF is using a bold font is to first make it a plain font. One way to do that might be `htmlLabel.setFont( htmlLabel.getFont().deriveFont(..) );` or to change it via the PLAF (but that will affect **all** labels, not just the ones used for rendering HTML).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JLabel text by default is already bold. You cannot double bold it, you can only unbold it and rebold it.

Try:

```html
<html><body style="font-weight: normal"><h3>Title</h3><ul><li><b>S</b>tuff</li><li><b>S</b>taff</li><li><b>S</b>tiff</li></ul></body></html>
```